# Simple Column Width

Tags: pdftex, tabularx

I'm new to Latex and have to create a form with pdftex. I have trouble with the column width in the following table:

```
% Font Sizes and Line Heights
\def \FSNormal {8}
\def \LHNormal {12}

{\fontsize{\FSNormal}{\LHNormal} \selectfont
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| m{6cm} | m{10cm} | X |}  
\hline  
    \multirow{2}{*}{{\large Prepared By:}} & Name: & Date: \\
    \cline{2-3} & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Rank:} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
```

[image]
Currently columns "Name" and "Date" both have same width. I want to make column "Name" wider and "Date" smaller. I tried to set column width with m{} and p{} without success. First column width is correct, but how can I set width of "Name" and "Date"?

Regards,

Obi

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Are you sure that `tabularx` is the correct environment for your purpose? From the abstract "A new environment, tabularx, is defined, which takes the same argu- ments as tabular*, but modifies the widths of certain columns, rather than the inter column space, to set a table with the requested total width. The columns that may stretch are marked with the new token X in the preamble argument." So either adjust the first argument or use a different environment.

Comment: I do not think I would use tabularx but if you are using it then the 2nd and 3rd columns are most likely not the same width, the 2nd column is 10cm, the third is whatever space is needed to reach the right margin, as you have provided no example, we can not know what that is, but it is unlikely to be exactly 10cm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two  `X` columns with unequal sizes, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow}

\begin{document}

% Font Sizes and Line Heights
\def \FSNormal {8}
\def \LHNormal {12}

{\fontsize{\FSNormal}{\LHNormal} \selectfont
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| m{6cm} | >{\hsize = 1.35\hsize}X| >{\hsize = 0.65\hsize}X |}
\hline
\multirow{2}{=}{{\large Prepared By:}} & Name: & Date: \\
\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Rank:} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adapt the values of the coefficients of `\hsize` to your needs. The condition is that, since there are two X columns, the sum of the coefficients be equal to 2.